# Python calls bash which calls bash with pipes (|)

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have a python script that calls a bash script, which calls another bash script that hangs only when called from python.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess 
print("Python")
subprocess.call(["/home/user/test/bash1.sh"])
```

bash1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash 1"
var=$(echo "Bash 1 var")
echo $var
/home/user/test/bash2.sh
```

bash2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash 2"
var=$(echo "Bash 2 var")
echo $var
randomkey=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
echo $randomkey
```

When I run ./bash1.sh everything works just fine. When I run test.py bash2.sh hangs at:

```
randomkey=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
```

I have a stinking feeling the pipes (|) aren't reaching their destinations. Any ideas how to make this work from test.py?

EDIT: Ubuntu VM with Python2.7

Comment: Can you share some more details about your environment (e.g. OS, Python version)? The code you posted works fine for me as-is on Ubuntu / Python 3.8.

Comment: Of course, edits made. Ubuntu VM with Python2.7.

I also tested this in Python3 and it's working just fine. I might have to reconsider my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading to Python3.7 from 2.7